# Drop down list on submit

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help with this.  All I want is a simple drop down that you select an option and then hit Download. Formatted like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="http://file/1234">file 1</option>
    <option value="http://file/1234">file 2</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Download</button>
```

This isn't pulling or getting inserted to a database, just a simple select an option and press download.  I could get it to work easily enough having it download on change, but that isn't how I need it to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
​$('button').click(function(){
  window.location = $('select').val();
});​
```

Comment: If the select field is in a form, they may want to prevent the button from actually submitting the form:

    $('button').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      window.location = $('select').val();
    });​

Answer (score 0):

Use this but it does not use button your file get download just after selection

```
 <form><select name="select" onchange="window.location.href= this.form.select.options[this.form.select.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="http://FILE">FILE1</option>
    <option value="http://FILE">FILE2</option>
    <option value="http://FILE">FILE3</option>
    <option value="http://FILE">FILE</option>
    </select></form>
```